# Delegation for Communication in Objective-C programming

Tags: objective-c, delegates, tableview

I have started coding in Objective-C for several days, and I am really confused about delegation. Could any one help?

In MyClassA.h

```
@protocol MyClassADelegate <NSObject>

- (void)haveANewMessage:(NSString*)message;

@end

@interface myClassA : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> {
    __unsafe_unretained id<MyDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyClassADelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In myClassB.h

```
@interface myClassB : NSViewController <MyTableViewDelegate,MyClassADelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) myClassA* instance;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSTableView* tableView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* messages;

@end
```

In myClassA.m

I have

```
[self.delegate haveANewMessage:@"Messages"];
```

and in myClassB.m

I have

```
- (void) haveANewMessage:(NSString *)message{
    NSLog(@"Get here!");
    [self.messages addObject:message ];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The problem is nothing is shown in my table view. Any help??
(Implemented Table-View Related Methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to look into, in this order.

1. Is `Get here!` appearing in your logs to signify your delegate method is being fired properly?
2. Did you set `self.delegate = myClassBInstance`
3. Is your TableView Delegate/DataSource setup correctly?
4. Has `self.messages` been initialized?

And as a side note, in Objective-C it is frowned upon for your class names to start with a lowercase letter. Class names should be CamelCase starting with a capital letter and variables should be camelCase starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! It works well. Sorry I can vote up because I am new on stackoverflow.

Comment: You can accept my post as the answer if it helped you. Just click the checkmark, you'll get some points for accepting the answer and be on your way to making a good profile :)